# Renaming a Yakuake session from commandline

Tags: ssh, kde-plasma, yakuake

Yakuake provides a hotkey and a GUI way to rename commandline tabs/sessions.

I'd like to do the same via the command line, so I can script it and use it in an alias. (My goal is that if I use an alias which does an SSH to some server, then the tab is renamed according to this servers name...)

I tried the suggestions shown here [Renaming a Konsole session from commandline after ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782159/renaming-a-konsole-session-from-commandline-after-ssh,but) so far no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since KDE4, one should use `qdbus` to control KDE apps (instead of deprecated and deleted DCOP).
For example, to change a title of the first session one may use:

```
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /Sessions/1 org.kde.konsole.Session.setTitle 1 "New title"
```

To explore available interfaces, methods and properties one may use `qdbusviewer`.

As a homework try to get a list of active sessions (before you going to change smth).

Comment: Cool, I'll try this out as soon as possible.

Comment: You pointed me the right way, but I was not able to make it work using your string. The following worked for me: `qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/tabs org.kde.yakuake.setTabTitle "`qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions org.kde.yakuake.activeSessionId`" "NEW TAB TITLE";`

Answer (score 3):

Like @fgysin pointed out, his command also works for me. BUT it needs the **`** character and not **"** for the subcommand :

```
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions org.kde.yakuake.activeSessionId
```

It gives :

```
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/tabs org.kde.yakuake.setTabTitle `qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions org.kde.yakuake.activeSessionId` "NEW TAB TITLE";
```

Comment: Confirming this form works for me locally.   Not sure how to get remote working.  The built-in GUI options seem to have no effect?